# Multiple entry templates per entry

Tags: templating, routes

Is there a way to have multiple entry templates per entry?

I'd like to create two different templates that display the same content/data in different ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they can live at different URL's, you could setup multiple routes under Settings->Routes. Give them different URL structures like so:

```
blog/slug loads mytemplatefolder/blog_template
another-url/slug loads mytemplatefolder/another_template
```

Comment: Works like a charm, never used routes before. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Actually, quick followup: I'm getting the following error: Variable "entry" does not exist.

When I try and set the variable entry on my own, it's coming up empty: {% set entry = craft.entries.section('brand').slug(slug) %} . 

Anything special I have to do when using routes to get entry to persist?

Comment: Are you getting the slug from the segment? Like so: {% set pageSlug = craft.request.getSegment(2) %}
{% set pageEntry = craft.entries.section('brand').slug(pageSlug).find() %}

Comment: Pretty close to what I had, getting a different error now when trying to echo out just the title. {{ pageEntry.title }} gives me a 'Key "title" for array with keys "0" does not exist' error.

Comment: You still have to do a for loop, even if it's just 1 entry. {% for entry in pageEntry %} {{ entry.title }} {% endfor %}